# How to install ubuntu along with pre-installed window 7 home premium (UEFI) in sony vaio sve14a15fn

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, vaio

I really tried alot to install ubuntu alongside with my preinstalled window 7. also, read many articles posted on internet regarding dual window installation. But nothing is working for me. So, I need to know the installation procedure for the same.

I made bootable pendrive of ubuntu 14.04 with the help of rufus software by choosing GPT partition scheme for UEFI. Also, i deleted by recovery disk and shrinked volume C. Then, restarted my computer and boot with ubuntu by hitting F11. I clicked on install ubuntu, chose language and select location. Then, setup asked about battery and space. After this I pressed continue, then i waited for 10-15 min but nothing happens further.
I tried a lot but nothing is happening beyond this step.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what you did and what was the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "made a bootable drive by choosing GPT partition scheme"? You do not need GPT on pendrive.

Comment: So how do i make pen drive bootable?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/167850

Comment: in this link, there is no discussion regarding ubuntu bootable pendrive. its only about CD/DVD bootable disk

Comment: OK. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: now, i again make a bootable pendrive with the help of ISOpower software. But still i am facing same problem, which i mentioned earlier.

Comment: Again my problem is not resolved. I cannt able continue

Comment: Whenever i reach to the window of preparing to install ubuntu, for best results please ensure that this computer:

Comment: I pressed continue after checking install this third party software... But after 15 minutes nuthing happens

Comment: Uncheck install third party software and updates. It may because of slow internet connection.

Comment: during installation i did not have internet connection

Comment: Try establishing an Internet connection, preferably via an Ethernet cable rather than Wi-Fi, and try again.

Comment: Still its not working...

Comment: I don't understand, why the setup stops working at this point. I cant able move further after the window " please ensure that this computer:". Its the really important for me to have dual OS. I tried many permutations and combinations, but still not able to install ubuntu on ma pc.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments it seems to me that there is a disconnect in understanding. Follow the steps below which should result in a clean install.

1. Create your bootable USB using Rufus
2. Reboot the pc, and boot the USB drive
3. Ensure that you have a wired internet connection
4. Uncheck third party apps and software (as this slows down the install greatly)
5. Allow time - The install for me in the past has taken almost 2 hours, don't be in a rush. Leave the room and come back later in the day or evening.

The biggest issue is your internet it must be hardwired, especially if you are choosing to install third party apps and software. Also be patient during the install.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with initially installing Ubuntu on my Toshiba, but it is possible. 


Try disabling the secure boot option in your BIOS, and if that doesn't work try switching to CSM boot mode, that should work.